# How Gson Parsed Custom Field

Tags: java, android, gson, android-databinding

I want parse Json using gson.
But gson not parsed specific jsonProperty into custom field
below is an example:

```
 `json String :  { "SONUMBER": "PSO1706000006  "}`
```

java class

```
  public class Item {


    @SerializedName("SONUMBER")
    @Expose
    public BindableString sONUMBER;
  }
```

BindableString.java  class

```
public class BindableString extends BaseObservable {

private String value = "";


public String get() {
    return !value.isEmpty() ? value : "";
}

public void set(String value) {
    if (!Objects.equals(this.value, value)) {
        this.value = value;
        notifyChange();
    }
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return value == null || value.isEmpty();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return value;
}

@BindingConversion
public static String bindableString(BindableString bindableString) {
    if (bindableString != null) {
        return bindableString.value;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

but when i parse json i getting null in Item.sONUMBER variable

I want parsed json  value into  Item.sONUMBER.

How should i achieve this there is any alternate availiable ?

Answer (score 1):

For this you can write custom type deserializer like this ,

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;

public class BindableStringDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<BindableString> {

    @Override
    public BindableString deserialize(JsonElement json, Type arg1,
            JsonDeserializationContext arg2) throws JsonParseException {
        BindableString bindableString = new BindableString();
        bindableString.set(json.getAsString());
        return bindableString;
    }

}
```

and create a Gson object like this then it will work,

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(BindableString.class, new BindableStringDeserializer());
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
```